Scraping economic calendar from investing.com
This code's goal is to create a pandas data frame from a data table that is scraped from a https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/ daily
the problem is that code is not working. I have tried scrap using by css_selector, class and ID
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/")
# Scrape the data
events = []

delay = 10  # seconds
WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(/html/body/div[6]/section/div[6]/table')))

# Locate the rows in the table
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[6]/section/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[]')

for row in rows:
    try:
        event = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[4]').text
        actual = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[5]').text
        previous = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td[7]').text

        events.append([event, actual, previous])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing row: {e}")

driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(events, columns=['Event', 'Actual', 'Previous'])

df.head()

df.to_csv('economic_calendar.csv', index=False)


there is a typo in your table xpath (bracket at the start), and the row xpath is invalid; remove the [] from the end. also you are better off scraping the api
